# how to get user's current location when application has been terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have gone through many tutorials but not able to find the right solution. I am working on location base application where I need to fetch user's current location, it doesn't matter even if the application is running in foreground or in background. So when i kill or terminate the application is it possible to fetch user's current location?

Comment: use signifigant monitoring update location  -- it shows the last object of the location

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get Location Updates for iOS 7 and 8 Even when the App is Suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have been following your suggested link from last two week, and also download the demo code from github and installed in my ipad but its not working. i want to call webservice in didUpdateLocations method but it is never called when app is terminated. can you please help me how can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. You will have to use method **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**. According to CLLocationManager documentation

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently
>   terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into
>   the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options
>   dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method of your application delegate contains the key
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your
>   application was launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch,
>   you must still configure a location manager object and call this
>   method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
>   location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
>   manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
>   before you start location services.

Comment: thank you for replay.... i followed  http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended this link from last two week...but didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didUpdateLocations is never called......i am testing on my ipad... can you please help me when this two method is called

Comment: didFinishLaunchWithOptions is called when an app is launched. It has nothing to do with location services. Check Privacy > Location Services of your ipad if location services are enabled for your app or not. Also from ios8  you need to get permission from the user to use location services.

Comment: yes i have already gave permission for location and location service is enable in my ipad.... let me know which method is called when application is terminate so i will call continuesoly my webservice in that method.

Comment: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application is called in app delegate on app termination.

Comment: i mean my application is already terminated then where how can i code for webservices to upload the lat long to the server continuesoly? applicationWillTerminate this method only called once when application is terminated.

Comment: You have to write the code in -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82675/discussion-between-bandish-dave-and-fawad-masud).