# iOS update location after kill app from Background

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, I want to track user location. For that i want to update user current location based on location accuracy(for High-> 15 min and Low -> 1 hour). When application run or in background than I can update location but after kill application from background, can't update location. I used timer to call it but after kill app(from background), it's not work.

So now what i do to update location based on location accuracy if user not run app in background also.

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: please check this link it will help you a lot 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended

Comment: this link has same thing you asked for check it it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended

Answer (score 2):

CoreLocation has 2 permisson:

1. One is for when the user use the app.
2. The second is updating location always even if it is not in used.

Use the second one, that's what GPS use for instance. But if you kill the app that is a going to stop updating location.

Comment: Yaa i use it. But after kill the app timer not work than how can i update location to server ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the NSLocationAlwaysUsage keys to your apps info.plist and then request permission when you wish to start monitoring.

Make sure you give a good description of why you want to always monitor bc I feel that really helps conversion rates.

Answer (score 0):

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    #define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

that code user location update only forground app running but not background run

```
        if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
        {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
```