# App not working in Background when iPhone is restarted

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, core-location

I have an app where I have enabled Background mode i.e, Location Updates. The app works in background perfectly until its restarted. Once restarted, the app doesn't get the location updates (The app isn't running). Anyway we can make the app run even after restarting the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chandan I give you very best solution from the below reference.

[Kindly go through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended)