# Meteor + Cordova: getting user's location when app is terminated

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I'm currently working on a location based Cordova + Meteor (iOS) mobile-app, where I need to keep an eye on the user's location, even when the app is terminated.

For this I have tried to implement the cordova-background-geolocation-lt plugin, but I'm having issues: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/221

Because of this I am thinking of writing my own native (obj-c/swift) plugin (partly using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742678/4541800)) that will get user's location and send it to the server.

My question is:

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742678/4541800):

> When iOS wants to return the location update to the app, it will help you to relaunch the app and return a key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to the app delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

When app is killed/terminated/suspended - Is it possible to relaunch only part of the Cordova app - only native code that is responsible for background geolocation tracking and posting it to the server without fully relaunch the whole app - JS part & Meteor part?

Comment: There is no option to do this. Cordova apps are all or nothing. Don't worry about the memory footprint, that's what the operating system looks after

Comment: @Mikkel, that's bad.. You see, the Meteor-Cordova app is not relaunching after it was killed and `locationManager` receives `SignificantLocationChanges`. `SignificantLocationChanges` should auto relaunch the app, but with Cordova & Meteor stack the app isn't relaunching - something prevents it.. so I thought that it is somehow possible to abstract geolocation (native module) from the rest of the Cordova app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to succesfully use [this](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) plugin in my `Meteor` + `Cordova` project after resolving this issue: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/221 . It turned out that this issue was due to the `Meteor`'s local server suspension after the app enters background state. It is specific to the `Meteor-Cordova` projects

Answer (score 1):

There is an Apple article here about background tasks: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Meteor generates the IOS code, but you can use XCode to modify the project and code somewhat, or I think you are correct in your approach to creating a plugin, because then you are in the native environment and can do these things.