# Fire 3 synchronous APIs once application wakes up from killed/ suspended state

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, geofencing

Geo-Fencing delegate methods **didExitRegion** and **didEnterRegion** working for all application states (Foreground / Background / Suspended and Killed state). Once any region gets passed, application need to hit 3 mutually dependent apis synchronously. All is working fine in foreground state, but **not in Suspended / Killed state**. Don’t know the exact reason of this fail.

One reason may be restricted awake time limit to perform all tasks in such case (killed/ suspended state). I tried **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler** , but its not helping me out.

```
- (void) beginBackgroundUpdateTask{

    _backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_backgroundTask];
    _backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didEnterRegion:(nonnull CLRegion *)region
{
    [kSharedAppDelegate beginBackgroundUpdateTask];

    NSString *locId = [region.identifier substringFromIndex:1];
    Recipe *recipe = [Recipe getSelectedReturnRecipeForLocationId:locId];
    if(recipe)
    {
        [self  callAPIOne:^(NSDictionary *dictResponse) {

          [self callAPITwo:params forAbc:NO];

        } withFailed:^(NSDictionary *dictResponse) {
                 [kSharedAppDelegate endBackgroundUpdateTask];
        } showLoader:NO];
    }
    else
        [kSharedAppDelegate endBackgroundUpdateTask];
}
```

Please help, if anyone has any advice about what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to call `endBackgroundUpdateTask` once all of the updates are complete, so call it from the final completion handler

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I have called endBackgroundUpdateTask, once all task completed inside callAPITwo:

Comment: Have you refered pushkit, putting app in specific category by taking advance permission from Apple will allow you.

Comment: @Hasya No, not tried yet. Could you please tell me, a bit more about it?

Comment: Check this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer myself, just to clear that ***above code is sufficient for such task. With above code all needful tasks are working in all application states (foreground/background/killed/suspended).***

My problem was in core data implementation. Once recipe object comes nil, I was skipping further code. It makes me feel like APIs are not firing because of restricted time limit in killed state.

Hope above code may help others with same issue.