# iOS Location Tracking Even App is Killed State And Call API Call

Tags: ios, core-location

I am working on app which require location tracking of customer even app is killed. I have to get location of customer even customers app is killed. Is think it is possible to track location using significant-change location service.

The significant-location change is working perfectly am getting location updates in delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

 }
```

I have to update to server when location update is happen.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
  Can i call API Like other api calls
 }
```

Is it possible to call API form this delegate or anything else to do ?
Any help appriciated. Thanks

Comment: No you cannot trace location when application is in killed state. You can trace wither app is running or in background state.

Comment: @ranto andrews, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/get-location-updates-for-ios-app-even-when-suspended

Comment: @Ashish i used same tutorial , its not mention about API Call to send data to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several test . i have checked web server data base. i found that location is updated. so it means that its possible to call api web even app is killed

Comment: I don't think so it is possible in kill mode, as apple not accept your application, if you do this then please share your code, so community can use it

Comment: it works with the help of significant location tracking feature in ios.

Comment: @Rinto Andrews, can you please share an example code on how to achieve this? Currently we are facing the same issue when app in killed state it is not calling the API.

Comment: @ Bhavesh Dhaduk,  have you got any solution to call API when app is in a killed state based on location?

Comment: it was working long back with significant location changes feature, not test recently. so i don't know.